# Не могу перекинуть время через props React

Tags: reactjs

Всем доброго дня. Помогите пожалуйста. Создаю страницу, на которой пользователь выбирает день и время записи на прием. У меня есть кнопки со временем, при клике на них должны передаваться props времени в другую компоненту, но вместо этого пишет object object. Вот мой код:

```
class Order extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
    date: new Date(),
    time: '',
    }
  }

  onClick = time => this.setState({ time });

  onChange = date => this.setState({ date });


  render() {
    return(<div>
      <Header/>
      <div className={styles.bodyContainer}>
        <p className={styles.back}>&#60; Назад</p>
        <h3>Расписание</h3>
      <div className={styles.calendarContainer}>
        <Calendar 
          className={styles.calendar}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          value={this.state.date}
        />
        <OrderDate value={this.state.date.toDateString()} time={this.state.time}/>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.time}>
      <div className={styles.morning}>
        <p>Утро</p>
        <button time={this.state.time} onClick={this.onClick}>10-00</button>
        <button time={this.state.time} onClick={this.onClick}>10-30</button>
        <button>11-00</button>
        <button>11-30</button>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.day}>
        <p>День</p>
        <button>12-00</button>
        <button>12-30</button>
        <button>13-00</button>
        <button>13-30</button>
        <button>14-00</button>
        <button>14-30</button>
        <button>15-00</button>
        <button>15-30</button>
        <button>16-00</button>
        <button>16-30</button>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.evening}>
        <p>Вечер</p>
        <button>17-00</button>
        <button>17-30</button>
        <button>18-00</button>
        <button>18-30</button>
        <button>19-00</button>
      </div>
      </div>

      </div>
      <Footer/>
    </div>)
  }
}
```

Не передается time в компоненту OrderDate, значение value(дата из календаря) передается и все работает.

Вот код из компоненты OrderDate:

```
class OrderDate extends Component {
  jump(){
    window.location.assign('http://localhost:3000/orderInfoClient');
  }

  render() {
    return(<div className={styles.orderDate}>
      <div className={styles.info}>
          <div className={styles.priceService}>
            Здесь будут цены и услуги

          </div>
          <div className={styles.adress}>
            <p>{this.props.value + ' ' + this.props.time}</p>
            <p>Санкт-Петербург, Россия</p>
            <p>191002</p>
            <button onClick={() => this.jump()}>Продолжить</button>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>)
  }
}

export default OrderDate;
```

Я понимаю, что скорее всего проблема кроется в том, что на входе у меня строка, и мне нужно преобразовать эти данные в другой формат, но я не понимаю в какой и как. Потому что функция toTimeString(), после time={this.state.time} в компоненте OrderDate не работает, а если быть точнее мне выдает ошибку, что это не функция.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь у вас скорее всего event приходит в качестве аргумента:

`onClick = time => this.setState({ time });`

Проверьте, пожалуйста, этот момент.

Я бы написал так:

```
 onClick = (event) => {
    this.setState({time: event.target.innerText})
 };
```

Comment: Выдает вот такую ошибку.Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ",".  Указывает на точку после event перед target.

Comment: Пардон, исправил ответ. Не указал свойство "time"

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо Андрей! Все заработало.

Comment: А не подскажете, как мне сделать, чтобы эти пропсы сохранялись? Компонента в которую они передаются находится на этой странице и все отображается. Но так же эта компонента есть на другой странице и в нее уже приходит 2 undefined.